# Edittext Field allow user to change field by button or edit and assign result to variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

I'm a newbie guy learning android programming to help be more efficient at work.
I have a very simple problem that I think should have a simple answer, I just can't find anything that works in my searching of eddittext, listener and edittext to variable.

Basically I have a Edittext field that should be updated by pressing a + or - button or by userinput.  I need that edittext field put into a variable so that I can use it in a calculation.  I want the calculation to occur after I hit either the + or - button and after (maybe during if it is easier) the user entering the text.

At the moment when I press the + or - button the resulting edit text is based on my int variable fuel but completely ignores the user input (because I can't get that user input to update my fuel variable).

What I need is.
1) The fuel variable to update based on user input so that when a subsequent + or - button is pressed the fuel variable is adjusted relative the the user input. i.e. send the user input to the fuel variable.

fuel is a global int variable.
fuelCalc is a method where I plan to do some calculations based on the fuel variable.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

The XML:

```
              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Fuel_load_field"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Fuel Load"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="+"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:onClick="addOneHundredtoFuel"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="-"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:onClick="subtractOneHundredtoFuel"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Here is the java:

```
public void addOneHundredtoFuel(View view) {

        fuel = fuel + 100;

        TextView fuelField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Fuel_load_field);
        fuelField.setText(String.valueOf(fuel));
        fuelCal(fuel);
    }

    public void subtractOneHundredtoFuel(View view) {

        fuel = fuel - 100;


        TextView fuelField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Fuel_load_field);
        fuelField.setText(String.valueOf(fuel));

        fuelCal(fuel);
    }

    public void fieldEntryFuel(View view) {

        EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Fuel_load_field);
        String fuelString = inputText.getText().toString();

        fuel = Integer.parseInt(fuelString);


        TextView fuelField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Fuel_load_field);
        fuelField.setText(String.valueOf(fuel));

        fuelCal(fuel);

    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Airfix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question...  You want a variable to be updated as the user enters text into an EditText, correct?  If so, you probably want to just out `TextWatcher`; it does exactly what you are looking to do if I understand correctly.

Example:

```
private final TextWatcher fuelWatcher = new TextWatcher(){
    EditText fuelLoadField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Fuel_load_field);

    @Override
    afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        fuel =  = Integer.parseInt(fuelLoadField.getText());
    }
}
```

Make sure you register that listener to your EditText object in your `onCreate()` by calling `fuelField.addTextChangedListener(fuelWatcher);`

Comment: William, you nailed my question but I can't get the code to work.  I put the fuelField.addTextChangedListener(fuelWatcher); in the oncreate method and I get an erorr on fuelField stating cannot resolve symbol fuelField.  I declared fuelField as a TextView which cleaned up that line.

The watcher gets some errors that I'm working on.  I think I migh finally have it.  How do I post follow up code on this site to I can illustrate the code that has worked and that which hasn't?

Comment: @Airfix 
What kind of error are you getting?  Also, you can add textwatcher like any other kind of listening by doing this: https://gist.github.com/wsmithsrs/bc1ba733f54e40f1ec7ed06128a23c58

Comment: Well I tried and still could not get it to work even with your example.  Here is an excerpt from my code is linked below. So here is my understanding.  The textwatcher is it's own method.  I need to call that method in the oncreate method so it runs when the app is started.  I couldn't call it properly.  I get an error  fuelWatcher(View) in mainActivity cannot be applied. Also in the afterTextChange part I get an error Non-static field "fuel" cannot be referenced from a static context. https://gist.github.com/Airfixed/d930ef55a8231bb9291db9f6635de683

Comment: Well I finally managed to get the listener working. I updated the gist to show the latest code.  I have a few more questions.  1) Is the way I handled the null string appropriate or is there a better way?  2) I'm going to have a lot of these listeners for each edittext field I assume I should put each listener into its own method and then call it from the oncreate method like you showed above (too late to try now). https://gist.github.com/Airfixed/d930ef55a8231bb9291db9f6635de683

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value from edit text field when user press any button you need just to call getText() on your EditText and store it as an int to use in future calculations `int userInput = Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText);`